# How to simulate Full IE cache for ASP.NET or Silverlight app

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, internet-explorer, cookies, browser-cache

What is the best approach to similate a browser full cache when debugging a Silverlight or ASP.NET application?  There is some intermittent behaviour that I want to make a determination if browser cache or full cookie cache is playing a part in this behaviour I am seeing.

Thanks for the help, in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not simulate IE cache that and at the same time debug your application and break point whats on code behind (if I understand well).

What you can do is to use the `Debug.Write(string)` functions inside your code to read whats going on, and you can read the out put of the events using the DebugView from sysinternals:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647